# GridView: ImageViews/ImageButtons not shown after inflating layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview

I try to display tiles within a GridView using a custom item layout. Each has a TextView as well as three image buttons below.
The XML item layout looks like this. Within the Android Studio designer, the layout looks exactly the way I want it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_edit" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_play" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_remove" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

However, after inflating within my GridView adapter, the TextView is visible but the three image views are not shown. Same happens when I use image button. Curiously, when I replace the three images by a normal button, it works.

Adapter code:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_subject, parent, false);
    float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    v.setLayoutParams(new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams((int)(180 * scale + .5f), (int)(180 * scale + .5f)));

    return v;
}
```

The defined tile size 180 x 180 is indeed large enough, at runtime, there's plenty of empty space where the images should be.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Thank you in advance

Comment: you put a lot of `layout_weight`..

Comment: in the inner `LinearLayout` add `weightSum="3"`

Comment: Thank you, has to be something else. I added weightSum as suggested, no changes. Then I removed the weights. No effect.

Comment: I believe the trouble is with the vector drawables , that you are using. I'm pretty sure with it since normal button worked for you

Comment: One solution is to change all vector drawables to pngs or add vector support..If you confirm I may put it as the answer to your question

Comment: The drawables are PNG images created with the Android Studio Image Asset assistant.

Comment: In addition, when I put the drawables on a regular button, it also works. I think the Button view has some default dimensions setting the ImageView/IMageButton don't have.

Comment: then add `vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true` under `defaultConfig ' in your build.gradle file and try

Comment: src instead of srcCombat: That's it!! Thank you so much, never would have find that out. Could you state an answer post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image assets you are using are vectors and you need to make some changes in your **build.gradle** file. add

```
 vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
```

under **defaultConfig**  in your build.gradle file.

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
     ...
     ... 
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  //add this
   }
}
```

In your Activity add this line of code

```
 AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
```

now you can set vector using `app:srcCompat` instead of `android:src`.